# Redmine send additional information to partial view called from a hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hook, partial-views, redmine

I want to add information in the redmine main project page. The [redmine plugin tutorial](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/plugin_tutorial) explains that it can easily be done using Hooks. I found that the hook that I want to use is the `view_projects_show_right` (from [Hooks_List](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks_List)).

In the [redmine hook documentation](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/hooks) I saw two ways of rendering partials.

**My hook**

```
class RedmineTestHookListener < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  def view_projects_show_right(context = {})
    context[:controller].send(:render_to_string, {
        :partial => 'test/test',
        :locals => context,
    })
  end
end
```

**My partial**

```
<div class="box">
  <h3 class="icon icon-news">Test</h3>
  <p><%= params %></p> <!-- {"controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"test-projet"}  -->
    <!-- I would like more information in the params -->
</div>
```

Of course I added the hook in my `init.rb`. Everything works fine but I want to add informations that come from the redmine database. Appending data to the context doesn't seem to work.

How can I send additional information to my partial view called from a hook ?

Using `render_on :view_projects_show_right, partial: 'test/test'` is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using extra argument in the `locals`

```
class RedmineTestHookListener < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  def view_projects_show_right(context = {})
    test = "123"
    context[:controller].send(:render_to_string, {
        :partial => 'test/test',
        :locals => { context: context, test: test},

    })
  end
end
```

And in the partial view

```
  <p><%= test %></p> <!-- "123" -->
```